# Comparing two array values in C

Tags: c, search, logic

I am writing a program for school project in C which compares the values of two arrays and gives specific results depending on what the input was from user. Basically my output values are two, **correctPosition** and **correctValue**.

**correctValue** is a value that is in the *valuesArray* but not at the correct position in *inputArray*, for example; value "4" is at index 1 of *valuesArray* but is located at index 2 of *inputArray*.

**correctPosition** is a value that at the same index in both *valuesArray* and *inputArray*. For example; value "3" is at index 1 of *valuesArray* and *inputArray*

If an x value between two arrays match, then it can either be a correctValue or correctPosition. Here's a visual representation:

```
valuesArray: 2 3 3
------------------
inputArray:  1 2 3
Answer: correctPosition = 1, correctValue = 1.

inputArray:  2 1 3
Answer: correctPosition = 2, correctValue = 0.

inputArray:  2 3 3
Answer: correctPosition = 3, correctValue = 0.
```

Here's the code I have written for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int inputArray[3], valuesArray[3];
  int correctNumber = 0, positionMatch = 0;
  int x, y;
  int visitedMatch[3];

  valuesArray[0] = 2;
  valuesArray[1] = 3;
  valuesArray[2] = 3;
  inputArray[0] = 1;
  inputArray[1] = 2;
  inputArray[2] = 3;

  for( x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    visitedMatch[x] = 0;
  }

  for(x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for(y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
      if (inputArray[x] == valuesArray[y] && visitedMatch[y] == 0) {
        if (x == y) { positionMatch++; } else { correctNumber++; }
        visitedMatch[y] = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("correctPosition = %d, ", positionMatch);
  printf("correctValues = %d\n", correctNumber);
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that for input 1 2 3, it first takes 1 and checks in the valuesArray and cannot find anything, so result stays 0. Then in second iteration where x = 1, it takes 2 and checks that it is in the array but not at the correct index, so correctValue counter becomes 1. Now in the final iteration where x = 2, it takes 3 and goes through the loop and finds the FIRST value "3" at index 2 because it was never visited before, so the final result becomes correctPosition = 0, correctValue = 2. If I write the input as 2 3 3, then it works fine and the output is correctPosition = 3, correctValue = 0. How can I fix this, what am I missing here?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to clarify what the actual assignment is here? Maybe it's just me but I'm having trouble figuring that out

Comment: I suggest you approach the problem a bit differently.  First scan the two arrays to find the exact matches (i.e. `positionMatch`).  Then use a histogram-based approach to compute a preliminary version of `valueMatch`: count how many of each symbol are present in `valuesArray` and how many of each are present in `inputArray`, and compute the sum over all the symbols of the minimum of those two values.  Then, subtract `positionMatch` from the preliminary `valueMatch` to eliminate the double-counting that you otherwise would have.

Comment: I'd suggest first checking if it is a correct position, before looking for the other less specific case. Use "short circuit" logic.

Comment: @TormundGiantsbane It's a board game called Master Mind, we need to make that using raspberry pi. So an array of secret values (valuesArray) is generated and user has to guess the correct sequence using physical button input.

Comment: So is it not possible to do it the current way I am trying?

Comment: @n.m. unfortunately we are required to allow duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other solution, a little more simple than the  John Bollinger algorithm :

- count the exact match and indicate these positions to be forget in both arrays
- for each non forget position from *inputArray* seach the value in non forget position of *valuesArray*

  - if found for the first time increment *correctNumber* and indicate this position in *valuesArray* to be forget
  - if found but not the first time just indicate this position in *valuesArray* to be forget

The implementation can be (because I am lazy right now I give the values for the _inputArray through the preprocessor identifier *I*, see the compilations)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SZ 3

int main() {
  int valuesArray[SZ] = { 2,3,3 };
  int inputArray[SZ] = { I };
  int correctNumber = 0, positionMatch = 0;
  int x, y;
  int forgetValues[SZ] = { 0 }; /* useless to give more value because want 0 for the others */
  int forgetInput[SZ] = { 0 }; /* useless to give more value because want 0 for the others */

  /* count the exact matches */
  for (x = 0; x < SZ; x += 1) {
    if (inputArray[x] == valuesArray[x]) {
      positionMatch += 1;
      printf("correct match %d index %d\n", inputArray[x], x);
      forgetValues[x] = forgetInput[x] = 1; /* do not consider that position later */
    }
  }

  /* count correct values */
  for (x = 0; x < SZ; x += 1) {
    if (!forgetInput[x]) {
      int v = inputArray[x];
      int found = 0;

      for(y = 0; y < SZ; y += 1) {
        if (!forgetValues[y] && (valuesArray[y] == v)) {
          if (!found) {
            /* first time, count it */
            correctNumber += 1;
            found = 1;
            printf("correct value %d index %d / %d\n", v, x, y);
          }
          forgetValues[y] = 1; /* do not consider it later */
        }
      }
    }
  }

  printf("correctPosition = %d, ", positionMatch);
  printf("correctValues = %d\n", correctNumber);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilations and executions ;

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -DI=1,2,3 c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
correct match 3 index 2
correct value 2 index 1 / 0
correctPosition = 1, correctValues = 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -DI=2,1,3 c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
correct match 2 index 0
correct match 3 index 2
correctPosition = 2, correctValues = 0
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -DI=2,3,3 c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
correct match 2 index 0
correct match 3 index 1
correct match 3 index 2
correctPosition = 3, correctValues = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in comments, I suggest a different approach.  Yours is a bit untidy algorithmically, because logically, the evaluation of `positionMatch` contributors involves comparing each input value to exactly one corresponding other position, whereas evaluation of `valueMatch` contributors involves comparing each input value to the whole board.

These would be cleaner if separated.  If you had to worry about handling very large boards, then it would also be relevant that separating the two steps could produce a solution whose cost scales linearly with the size of the board instead of quadratically.  Specifically, the approach I'm suggesting is

1. Scan the two arrays once to compute the `positionMatch` count and to build for each array a histogram of the number of appearances of each symbol.
2. Scan the two histograms, computing a sum of the the minimum, for each symbol, of the number of counts for that symbol in the two histograms.    This yields the total number of correct numbers, but does not distinguish those in the correct position from those incorrect positions.
3. Subtract the `positionMatch` computed in (1) from the sum computed in (2) to yield the `correctNumber`.

With that said, however, you should be able to tweak your current code to compute the correct results.  The main thing missing is avoiding use of an element of the `valuesArray` that should provide a `positionMatch` to instead provide a `correctNumber`.  But that's a situation that you can test.  When you detect a match (`inputArray[x] == valuesArray[y] && visitedMatch[y] == 0`), you presently exercise one of only two alternatives, depending on whether `x == y`.  To compute the counts correctly, you should instead have three:

- If `x == y` then increment `positionMatch` and break from the inner loop.  (You can mark the position visited, too, but you don't need to do.)
- Otherwise, if `inputArray[y] == valueArray[y]` then *do nothing*.  That element of `valueArray` did or will contribute to `positionMatch`, so it should not contribute to `correctNumber`.  Just continue to the next inner-loop iteration.
- Else increment `correctNumber`, mark position `y` visited, and break from the inner loop

---

Alternatively, you could adapt your current approach to simulate my suggested one without actually constructing physical histograms.  These changes would be needed:

- In the outer loop, determine whether to increment `positionMatch`.  Continue to the inner loop either way.
- In the inner loop, ignore whether `x == y`, and instead increment `correctNumber` and mark the position visited whenever you find a match.  This is a substitute for computing and evaluating histograms.
- at the end, subtract `positionMatch` from `correctNumber` before reporting the results.

Comment: I will try to fix my current method based on your suggestions to get the idea of what I was doing wrong, and then implement the first suggestion which makes more sense. Thank you for the help!

Comment: your answer was already accepted when I published mine, I did not think that the OP would have changed its mind, to be fair in counter part I upvote your answer ;-)